# Trying to make a multivalue dictionary that inherits from Dictionary - C# to VB conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

Hi I am trying to convert this C# code to VB

```
class MultiValueDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{

   public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   {
      if(!ContainsKey(key))
         Add(key, new List<TValue>());
      this[key].Add(value);
   }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
Class MultiValueDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of TKey, List(Of TValue))

    Public Sub Add(key As TKey, value As TValue)
        If Not ContainsKey(key) Then
            Add(key, New List(Of TValue)())
        End If
        Me(key).Add(value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it gives an error on the line:

```
Add(key, New List(Of TValue)())
```

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TValue)' cannot be
>   converted to 'TValue'.

I am not really that clear about the TKey TValue notation, can somebody explain what this error is telling me? What should it read instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does not [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) enough for that?

Comment: I think there should be some difference referring to function overloading in VB.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, better inherit interface rather than a `list` itself.

```
... : Dictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>>
```

Second, your `Add` mthod calling seems to call itself. Try calling base' method.

```
MyBase.Add(key, New List(Of TValue)())
```

Third, why don't you just use `Lookup<,>`? Its so simple to group elements by keys.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give Lookup a go.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly calling the method on the base class instead:

```
MyBase.Add(key, New List(Of TValue)())
```

The code conversion utility you used does not allow for VB's suckiness :)